# struggling with getting birthdays in the next 2 weeks from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

Found a few solutions on stack for this but people all seems to be asking it different ways none of which seems to match what i'm doing so their answers dont really help.  Basically I have the below.

```
 $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM user WHERE WEEK( userDOB ) < WEEK( DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 2 WEEK) ) AND WEEK( userDOB ) >= NOW()");
```

I'm trying to find all birthdays in the database between today and 2 weeks from today.  Currently I'm storing birthdays in the sql format   yyy-mm-dd

I also have this version of the same query

```
        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userDOB  BETWEEN CURDATE()  AND  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL +14 DAY)");
```

Which I found here...
https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/175275/birthday-reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just solved it with the WEEK function in sql

here is the solution for anyone looking

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM user WHERE WEEK( userDOB )  BETWEEN WEEK( CURDATE() )  AND  WEEK( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL +14 DAY) )");
```

Answer (score 1):

Store them as timestamps (seconds since 1970 or something) and just search for all data which is between now and current timestamp + 3600 * 24 (a day) * 14 ( a week)

http://php.net/manual/de/function.time.php

`time()` gives you the current timestamp.

Comment: This is the best way IMO. I always use Unix Timestamp as it is really easy to calculate.

Comment: 24 hours does not always equal 1 day, so using simple multiplication can lead to problems.

Comment: @Jakar excuse me? Ofc 24 hours equal a day.

Comment: When time changes, a day is not 24 hours. If Day0 is 24 hours, then Day1 goes from 2:00 am to 1:00 am (DST change), then Day0 + 48 hours = Day1 23:00 instead of Day2 0:00 as expected

Comment: I think the OP is looking for upcoming birthdays. Birthdays aren't dates of birth, but rather they are dates of birth with the year changed to the current year, or next year if you're near the end of the current year. There happens to still be a fraction of the population whose dates of birth can't be represented by `timestamp` data types because they were born before the beginning of 1970.